# What does reducing an NPC's stamina do?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

So lets say you drain an NPC'S stamina with Poisons/Absorb Enchant/Etc...

What does this mean for me: the player?

Unfortunately it's not like morrowind where they collapse (Man I wish it was still like that), but besides not being able to do power bashes, what benefit does this actually give the player?

Are they not able to block?
Do weapons do more damage?
....Anything else worthwhile maybe?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The effect of having no stamina on NPCs is the same as your character having no stamina.

- can't perform power moves
- can't sprint
- can't shield bash

Verified from [uesp](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Stamina)

Comment: Doesn't blocking with no stamina cause staggering? (or is this wrong)

Comment: No, but blocking a power attack causes you to stagger.